# I want to Unlock my Buttons OnGui after finishing the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I disabled my Guibuttons by using `GUI.enabled = false` 
How can I re-enable it each time a game finishes ?

please help thanks :)

```
#pragma strict

var sign : Texture;
var challenge1 : Texture;
var challenge2 : Texture;
var challenge3 : Texture;
var LevelOneEnabled = true;
var LevelTwoEnabled = false;
var LevelThreeEnabled = false;
var Score : TextMesh;
var Score2 : TextMesh;
var Score3 : TextMesh;
function Start(){

}
function Awake(){
Score.text = "Highscore: "+ PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JeepneyScore");
Score2.text = "Highscore: "+ PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JeepneyScore2");
Score3.text = "Best Time: "+ PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("JeepneyScore3");
}
function OnGUI()
{


if(GUI.Button(Rect(100,100,250,250),sign)){
Application.LoadLevel("Signs");
}
if(GUI.Button(Rect(550,500,280,80),"Back")){
Application.LoadLevel("Menu");
}
GUI.enabled = LevelOneEnabled;
if(GUI.Button(Rect(400,100,250,250),challenge1)){
Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene");
}
GUI.enabled = LevelTwoEnabled;
if(GUI.Button(Rect(700,100,250,250),challenge2)){
Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene2");
}
GUI.enabled = LevelThreeEnabled;
if(GUI.Button(Rect(1000,100,250,250),challenge3)){
Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene3");
}

}
```

please help me someone it would be a great thanks for me

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to enable "Leveltwo" after finishing "leveone",just make your boolean "LevelTwoEnabled=true" at the time of completing "levelone".